# Replacing View Controllers in .xib file

Tags: ios

I have a main .xib file that contains an App Delegate, Window, and View Controller ABC objects. When I click on the object "View Controller ABC", it shows it's outlets defined in the .h class file.

Now I want the main .xib to show a different View Controller XYZ on first init. How do I replace the view controllers? I tried dragging a new View Controller object, but I don't know how it references the XYZ class.

App Delegate .h

```
@interface JabberClientAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
    UIWindow *window;
    ViewControllerXYZ *viewController;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet ViewControllerXYZ *viewController;
```

App Delegate .m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    [DDLog addLogger:[DDTTYLogger sharedInstance]];

    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

I tried to replace the View Controller property with the new XYZ class. But the .xib doesn't get updated.

Any suggestions how to update the .xib?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you need to change the kind of class for your `UIViewController` on the XIB, so you can access the `IBOutlets` of your XYZ `UIViewController`. Like this:

[image]